# Properly insulating crawl space

Tags: insulation, crawlspace

Currently my crawl space has no insulation. The previous owner put gravel on the ground.

I was told by my home inspector that I would save some money on energy costs. However, I'm not sure what's recommended?

Should I rake up the gravel and put a plastic moisture barrier on the ground then rake the gravel back over? Should I staple insulation into the joists instead or do both?

Comment: Where are you located (or what is the climate)? Presumably the crawlspace is non-conditioned space, and you intend to keep it that way? You should probably also look through the [crawlspace+insulation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawlspace+insulation) tags as some of the similar questions regarding insulation and venting may be helpful.

Comment: State of Kansas (near KC). It is non-conditioned space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vapor barrier should go on the hot humid side of the insulation . In Kansas, the critical season is winter and the hot humid side will be the interior heated space. It will not be the ground or the exterior side of the insulation.

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with insulation. The type I know of has paper on one side (faced). So from what I understand, you want the faced side facing upwards towards the floor above? Similar to how an attic has the facing down?